# signInWithRedirect should redirect to a custom url / home url

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase signInWithRedirect in my react js web app , everything is working fine but when i use google sign in it redirect me again to the sign in page , insted i want it to redirect to the home page or to the original url before login.
for eg: let home url be  xyz.com
and sign in page url be xyz.com/login
and when i use google signInWithRedirect it redirect me to xyz.com/login , instead i want it to redirect to xyz.com .

I am using this code for google sign in :

```
signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
```

I also tried getRedirectResult for redirecting but this doesn't help as it redirects after loading that component first

```
signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
getRedirectResult(auth)
      .then((result) => {
        navigate("/");
})
```

Comment: please let me know if this is possible or not

Comment: @alexMamo can you help me with this issue also please?